# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm is undefined" (found in <Root>)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I recently switched to class components with typescript, and get this error when on my website.
This error is on firefox but on chrome i get

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '$createElement' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)
```

Looking It up The closest answer I could find was about switching components to component in the router file. But I've checked and all of mine seem to be just fine.

Here are some of exerts from my files

Nav.vue

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

import Db from './Db.vue';

@Component({
  components: { Db }
})
export default class Nav extends Vue {
  get user() { return this.$store.state.user };
  get token() { return this.$store.state.token };

  logout() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setState', {
      token: '',
      user: '',
      db: '',
      databases: []
    });
    this.$router.push('/');
  };
};
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({

})
export default class Login extends Vue {
  //state
  username = '';
  password = '';
  usernameError =false;
  passwordError = false;
  error: string|number = '';

  //methods
  async login(): Promise<void> {
     ...
  };
  ...


  //lifecycle
  mounted() {
    console.log("HELLO WORLD I AM")
    if (this.$store.state.token)
      this.$router.push('/discover');
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is the google error in full

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$createElement' of undefined
    at render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"713dcdf0-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90& (app.js:1461), <anonymous>:6:16)
    at options.render (index.js?6435:83)
    at createFunctionalComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3058)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3231)
    at _createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3428)
    at createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3353)
    at vm.$createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3488)
    at Proxy.render (main.ts?bc82:19)
    at Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
eval @ main.ts?bc82:15
./src/main.ts @ app.js:17260
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:727
fn @ app.js:101
1 @ app.js:17658
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:727
(anonymous) @ app.js:794
(anonymous) @ app.js:797
```

fire fox in full

```
TypeError: "_vm is undefined"
    render App.vue:3
    render index.js:83
    VueJS 5
    render main.ts:19
    VueJS 6
    <anonymous> main.ts:15
    ts app.js:17260
    __webpack_require__ app.js:727
    fn app.js:101
    1 app.js:17658
    __webpack_require__ app.js:727
    <anonymous> app.js:794
    <anonymous> app.js:797
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this error while working with `nuxt`. The issue was happening during page refresh, but was not present if I'd go to the page with problem through nuxt-link.

It got resolved after I've replaced `v-if` with `v-show` in one of my components where I've been pulling server-side async data and using vuex getters (state is also modified server-side) to modify template.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by rebuilding and copy pasting.

Comment: Rebuilding and copy pasting what?