# Nuxt error : nodeOps.tagName(...) is undefined in Vue framework's 'createPatchFunction'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

in my nuxt app , after changing route using `this.$router.push({ path: '/path' })` i got the `nodeOps.tagName(...) is undefined` in firefox , in chrome i get `cannot get access to .toLowerCase() of undefined` in the same line .

it happens in `createPatchFunction` of `vue.runtime.esm.js` versions:  `nuxt:^2.14.12, vue:^2.6.12`

```js
function createPatchFunction (backend) {
  // ...
  // some more vue framework code here
  // ...
  function emptyNodeAt (elm) {
    // the following line throws error and app crashes
    return new VNode(nodeOps.tagName(elm).toLowerCase(), {}, [], undefined, elm)
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** the `elm` argument is of type html comment .

**UPDATE-2:** `package.json` and `nuxt.config.js` files:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-number-input": "^1.2.1",
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.5.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.4",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.12",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-numeric-input": "^1.0.6",
    "vuex-pathify": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.1.12",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";

export default {
  mode: "universal",
  target: "static",
  css: ["@/assets/scss/global.scss"],
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/api/index.js",
    "~/plugins/sassVaribles/index.js",
    "~/plugins/datePicker/index.client.js",
    "~/plugins/globalComponents.js",
  ],
  components: false,
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/vuetify", "@nuxtjs/style-resources"],
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxt/content",
    "@nuxtjs/svg",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy"
  ],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ["@/assets/scss/main.scss"]
  },
  env: {
  },
  server: {
    port: 8089,
    host: "0.0.0.0"
  },
  axios: {
    baseURL: ""
  },
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    rtl: false,
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      default: "light",
      disable: false,
      options: {
        customProperties: true,
        variations: true
      },
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: "#5050a0",
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: "#dddcec",
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        },
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        },
        custom: {
          color: {
            background: {
              default: "#fff",
              paper: "#fff",
              paperOverlay: "#fff"
            },
            text: {
              primary: "#000",
              secondary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
              disabled: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
              hint: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
              icon: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you please give us more info with your `nuxt.config.js` and `package.json` files?

Comment: What about the file where you do have `this.$router.push({ path: '/path' })`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got `Nuxt error : nodeOps.tagName(...)` along with following `vm undefined` error:
[[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm is undefined" (found in <Root>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079013/vue-warn-error-in-render-typeerror-vm-is-undefined-found-in-root/71319516#71319516)

It got resolved after I've replaced `v-if` with `v-show` in one of my components where I've been pulling server-side async data and using vuex getters (state is also modified server-side) to modify template.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an older version of Node? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2385#issuecomment-358111543

Try to upgrade it to the latest LTS aka 14 and double-check that you got the latest version of Nuxt too.

Comment: thank you , i have node 14 . i can fix it in develop mode by changing vue source code from node_modules , it just needs some null checking . but it uses another unknown to me minified files for production , only if i could change those in webpack....